# Прогресс бар по контуру фигуры

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо сделать прогресс бар. Вокруг определенной картинки (в данном случае векторной, пример картинки прикрепил) сделать обводку в виде полоски в 2px голубым цветом которая будет прямо по границе картинки ползти.

Результат решения должен быть не просто анимированная картинка с анимацией рисования, а чтобы можно было выставлять на сколько % закрасить прогресс бар!

```html
<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Думал вокруг картинки нарисовать векторную полоску, но вот не знаю можно ли ее как то анимировать, чтобы рисовалась частями

Comment: Думал с Canvas поразбираться, там то точно можно сделать, но ни разу еще с ним не сталкивался.

Answer (score 3):

Из идей только так. Сделать конкретно по периметру не представляю возможным.

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 110px;
  height:100px;
  
}
.progress{
  position:absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation-name:progress;
  animation-duration:5s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
svg{
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
}
svg.blue{
  transform:scale(1.07, 1.1);
  overflow:hidden;
}
@keyframes progress{
  from{
    width:0px;
  }
  90%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
    width:100%;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
      <svg class="blue" fill="#3498db" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <svg class="black" fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
      <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"/>
    </svg>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Примерно так я тоже делал, тут то сложности собственно нет никакой. Я именно хочу сделать чтобы вокруг всей картинки бежала полоса. Уже целую неделю как хочу )) испробовав кучу способов, начал изучать Canvas, видимо через него придется рисовать.

Comment: Canvas — это растровая графика, а SVGшка у тебя векторная. Несостыковочка получается. Тут только SVG анимашка в твоём случае. Увы, я ею не владею((

Comment: Ну Canvas как альтернатива, хотелось бы без него, буду ждать, вдруг найдется решение )

Answer (score 3):

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 50s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 26 26" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="1"
    />
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="CSS"
             from="0% 100%" to="100% 0%"
             begin="0s" dur="5s" 
             repeatDur ="5s" />
</svg>

<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 26 26" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="1"
    />
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="CSS"
             from="0% 10%" to="50% 0%"
             begin="0s" dur="5s" 
             repeatDur ="5s" />
</svg>

<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 26 26" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="1"
    />
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="CSS"
             from="0% 0%" to="100% 100%"
             begin="0s" dur="5s" />
</svg>

<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 26 26" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="1"
    />
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="CSS"
             from="0" to="100%"
             begin="0s" dur="5s" />
</svg>

<br>

<svg fill="#000000" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 26 26" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"
    class="path" 
    stroke="red" 
    stroke-width="1" 
    />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так, но здесь скорее вопрос к самой свг, потому как у нее "странные пути" и анимация в 5s рисует быстро контуры вокруг самого объекта и внутри объекта, но если сделать "правильную свг", то в приницпе получится то что ожидается:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 15s linear alternate infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <svg fill="#000000" height="300" viewBox="0 0 23 28" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <path stroke="red" stroke-width="1" d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM14 13v4h-4v-4H7l5-5 5 5h-3z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А как передавать значение прогресса, на сколько % закрасить прогресс?